# How can I extract address, city, state and Postal code from a text separated by * using REGEXP_SUBSTR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

`REGEXP_SUBSTR('4550 Montgomery Avenue*Toronto*Ontario*M4A 2S3*', '(.*? ){2}(.*?),')`

I get a list of dynamic text which contains address, city, state and Postal code separated by *.
Need to exact address, city, state and Postal code using REGEXP_SUBSTR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), because it would be simpler than regular expressions for this task.

```
mysql> set @string = '4550 Montgomery Avenue*Toronto*Ontario*M4A 2S3*';

mysql> select 
 substring_index(@string, '*', 1) as address,
 substring_index(substring_index(@string, '*', 2), '*', -1) as city,
 substring_index(substring_index(@string, '*', 3), '*', -1) as state_province,
 substring_index(substring_index(@string, '*', 4), '*', -1) as postal_code;

+------------------------+---------+----------------+-------------+
| address                | city    | state_province | postal_code |
+------------------------+---------+----------------+-------------+
| 4550 Montgomery Avenue | Toronto | Ontario        | M4A 2S3     |
+------------------------+---------+----------------+-------------+
```